# how to redirect to html page using Express and then use node modules in that HTML file

Tags: html, node.js, express, redirect, node-modules

I have an index.js file which has Express and some other modules. What the best way to redirect from index.js file to an html page using Express and then use node modules in that HTML file?

Comment: pure js  `window.location.href = 'newurl'`

Comment: how to use node modules in the HTML file??

Comment: Node Modules in html????

Comment: I want to fetch data from server and show it on HTML using a Node module. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the question you are asking is in reference to redirecting to different pages using your index.js file, but if I am translating your questions correctly you may be referencing creating an .ejs file to navigate to different routes within your express app.

An EJS file contains code written in the Embedded JavaScript (EJS) templating language, which is utilized to generate HTML markup using JavaScript.

This would require you to:
`npm install ejs --save`

- Implement ejs into your index.js file
  `app.set("view engine", "ejs");`
- create as many individual .ejs files as necessary
- Then write code to app.get to different routes

`app.get("/", function(req, res){ res.redirect("/index.html");  });`

- etc. for how ever many files you desire

Does this answer your question or was I totally off base from your original question?

Comment: Actually, I am fetching data from a server in my index.js and want to transfer that data in HTML Canvas gauge present on index.html to automatically move the gauge needle depending on the value.

Comment: I have a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77418080/how-to-redirect-a-html-page-request-with-express. Is it possible to check for individual pages?